# Not able to Seralize QHash to DataStream

Tags: qt, qhash

while leaning about QHash and serializing QHash to DataStream I got an error with the following code.

```
typedef QHash <quint32,QString> hashtype1;
typedef QHash <QLocale::Language,hashtype1> hashtype;

hashtype1 hash;
hash.insert(1, "Key1");
hash.insert(2, "Key2");

hashtype hash1;
hash1.insert(QLocale::English, hash);
hash1.insert(QLocale::French, hash);

QByteArray ba;
QByteArray ba1;
QDataStream ds(&ba, QIODevice::ReadWrite);
QDataStream ds1(&ba1, QIODevice::ReadWrite);
ds << hash;
ds1 << hash1;

qDebug() << ds.device()->readAll();
ds.device()->reset();
ds1.device()->reset();

hashtype1 hashcopy;
ds >> hashcopy;

hashtype hash1copy;
ds1 >> hash1copy;
```

The last statement is giving an error saying
/usr/include/qt4/QtCore/qdatastream.h:362: error: no match for ‘operator>>’ in ‘in >> k’

I am not able to correct this..
Am I doing somthing wrong??
How can I correct this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that there are no `QDataStream` operators for `QLocale::Language`.  When streaming out this works because it gets automatically converted to an integer type.  It can't do this for streaming in.  So you will either need to change your `QHash` to use a different template parameter for the key or write streaming operators for `QLocale::Language` (which should be trivial, you just need to cast it to/from int).